# if a variable is referenced inside a function then what happens

Tags: php, reference

```
function a(&$c, &$d){
    $c = &$d;
}

$a = 1;
$b = 2;

a($a, $b);
echo $a;
```

output is 1,but shouldn't it be outputting 2 as $c is referencing $d. $c and $a reference to the same value,then $c refer to the value of $d which refer to $b so ultimately $a should refer to $b, isn't it correct?

Comment: You cannot swap references inside the function and expect it to be reflected outside of it.

Comment: so making a reference inside a function is useless

Comment: so what $c is refering to now?

Answer (score 0):

For the operation you seek you must remove the ampersand reference used within the function a.

**Example**

```
function swap (&$one, &$two) {
    $tmp = $one; // One is stored temporarily
    $one = $two; // Two is stored in One
    $two = $tmp; // Temporary data retrieved and stored in two
    unset($tmp); // Temporary variable destroyed
}

// Set the variables
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

echo $a . " - " . $b . "<br />"; // See output as: 1 - 2
swap($a, $b);
echo $a . " - " . $b; // See output as: 2 - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

in line

> $c = &$d;

$a is referring to the address of $b but not to $b, then you can try this:

```
<?php 
    function foo(&$c, &$d){
        $c = $d;
    }

    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;

    foo($a, $b);
    echo $a;
?>
```